# Does the shape of a pattern influence the performance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, clustering, group-differences, pattern-recognition

Given I have a feature set with around 6 features. These features represent the shape of a pattern. Each feature is a point in two dimensional space. Hence, an observation looks like:
$$(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), … (x_6, y_6)$$
Just to have an image in mind, the points represent a chart pattern like this where $(E1, E2, … , E6)$ are the points:
[image: SHS formation example]

Additionally, I have a scalar or vector for each feature set containing information about the performance of an observation (in this case a pattern). This could be just a number indicating the performance (or e.g. a distribution).

**I want to analyze if the shape of the pattern, influences the performance of the pattern.**

Under $H_0$ the shape should not be influencing the performance. Hence, similar shaped patterns should be all over the different performance categories. 
Under $H_A$ the shape influences the performance. Hence, similar patterns should be in the same performance category. 
[image]
The groups won’t be perfect and in each group there will be patterns with different performance categories. Thus, a test needs to be constructed, to test if groups there is a significant amount of similar shaped patterns in a performance category (or groups contain a significant amount of patterns from a specific performance category).

I am sure this is a common problem but I do not know what to google for or what would be a standard approach here. Any hints/ideas?